# How flexible is Titanium? Can I add custom controls

Tags: android, mobile, titanium

I am looking [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) as a potential technology for targeting Android, BlackBerry and iPhone. However, I am finding it hard to cut through the hype on the website!

The application I have in mind is farely simple, suing common UI controls, so Titanium would likely be a good fit, however, what if I want to add more complex controls such as a Chart? does Titanium have a common API for charts that is cross-platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium is javascript so you could build your own or find a javascript chart maker. Personally I would just use a `webview` to show something like [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html).